# Test connection only reports successes

Tags: powershell-3.0

First let me start by saying I am new to Powershell. I wrote a script to use Test-Connection to check whether our systems and servers are up or down. I know this has been done before but I learn better by doing so I took a shot. It helped me with formatting the html output as well. The problem is that it will only output the successful systems. If the system is offline or times out, it will show an error at the commandline but not in the output. I would like the status column to show success or fail but for now even 1 or 0 would work.
Here's the code I am using. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
$OutputFile = ".\CompStatusResults.htm"
$InputFile =  ".\Full_List.txt"
$ServerList= get-content $InputFile
$header=@"
<h2 style='color:#8B0000;'>$(Get-Date) - System Status Report</h2>
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #63B8FF;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #F6F9ED}
TR:Hover TD {Background-Color: #C1D5F8;}
</style>
<Title>Systems Group Membership </Title>
"@
$results = Foreach($ServerName in $ServerList)
{Test-Connection $ServerName -Count 1 | Select Address, IPV4Address,StatusCode;}

$results | ConvertTo-Html -as Table -head $style -PreContent $header |Format-Table -Autosize | Out-File $OutputFile 
&($OutputFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

It never fails after you ask a question you find an answer on your next search. I searched this time just for Test-Connection and found this post [test-connection output to csv file with hostname and IPaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757258/test-connection-output-to-csv-file-with-hostname-and-ipaddress)

by incorporating some of this code into mine it now does what I want it to. This is the new code. It might not be the best way and if anyone wants to improve it be my guest but it does work. Thanks for having this site available

```
$OutputFile = ".\CompStatusResults.htm"
$InputFile =  ".\Full_List.txt"
$Servers= get-content $InputFile

$collection = $()
foreach ( $_Server in $servers)
{
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $_Server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
if (Test-Connection $_Server -Count 2 -ea 0 -quiet)
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Active"
} 
else 
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Inactive" 
}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
$collection += $serverStatus

}
#$collection | Export-Csv .\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation

$header=@"
<h2 style='color:#8B0000;'>$(Get-Date) - System Status Report</h2>
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #63B8FF;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #F6F9ED}
TR:Hover TD {Background-Color: #C1D5F8;}
</style>
<Title>Systems Group Membership </Title>
"@

$collection | ConvertTo-Html -as Table -head $style -PreContent $header |Format-Table -Autosize | Out-File $OutputFile 
&($OutputFile)
```